# subgroup for user path in gitlab.com

Tags: gitlab

How can I create a group (or it is a subgroup) for my user path in gitlab.com ?

If my user at gitlab.com is `myUser` then I've got a gitlab path
`https://gitlab.com/myUser`.

If I create a new group `myGroup` this group has the path
`https://gitlab.com/myGroup`.

What I want to archieve is a group path
`https://gitlab.com/myUser/myGroup`.

Yes, it is possible to create a subgroup for myGroup but this leads to
`https://gitlab.com/myGroup/mySubgroup`.

How can I create a *subgroup* directly for my user path ?

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** By changing my username into something different from the name I want to use as basepath, I was able to solve my problem. Now, my username is xyz which leads to `https://gitlab.com/xyz` and I'm able to use the URL `https://gitlab.com/myUser/subgroup/project` as path.